# Генерация распорядка работы из массива

Tags: php, массивы

Есть масив:

```
array(
  'mon' => array(
    'workday' => 1,
    'from' => '09:00',
    'to' => '18:00'
  ),
  'tue' => array(
    'workday' => 1,
    'from' => '09:00',
    'to' => '18:00'
  ),
  'wen' => array(
    'workday' => 0,
    'from' => '09:00',
    'to' => '18:00'
  ),
  'thu' => array(
    'workday' => 1,
    'from' => '10:00',
    'to' => '19:00'
  ),
);
```

Задача: собрать из него строку типа: **Пн-Вт:** 09:00-18:00, **Чт:** 10:00-19:00, **Ср:** вых.

Пробовал сделать с помощью перебора массива и сравнения следующего дня с предыдущим и проверкой на **workday** собрать массив из групп, но столкнулся с проблемой - как из списка дней собрать диапазон, а не перебирать через запятую каждый день.

З.Ы. - возможно есть более грамотное решение задачи?

Comment: Формируйте из этого другой массив в котором ключами будут начало и конец работы в виде `09:00-18:00`, а значениями элементов - массивы с номерами дней. Нерабочие дни в нулевой элемент массива можно сохранять. Думаю, так легче будет вывести диапазоны дней по одинаковым часам работы.

Comment: Очень годное замечание, сейчас попробую.

Comment: Столкнулся с проблемой когда Пн-Пт: 09-18, Вт: 08-17, порядок дней вываливается в 0, я так думаю, что надо дни привязать к номерам и выстроить их в порядке следования...

Comment: я про номера и писал, чтобы можно было порядок наводить.

Comment: Прсто у меня исходный массив - 'mon' => 'Пн', 'tue' => 'Вт' и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге получилось вот так:

```
public $workflow;

public function run() {
    $workflow = array();

    foreach ($this->workflow as $day => $data) {
        if ((bool)$data['workday'] === true) {
            $time = $data['from'] . '-' . $data['to'];
            $workflow[$time][] = Object::getDay($day);
        } else {
            $workflow[0][] = Object::getDay($day);
        }
    }

    $this->render('index', array(
        'workflow' => $workflow,
    ));
}
```

Спасибо @cyadvert за подсказку.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю вот такой вариант:

```
$t = Array();
foreach($days as $d=>$dData) {
    switch($dData["workday"]) {
    case '0':
        $dKey = 'вых.';
        break;
    default:
        $dKey = $dData["from"] . '-' . $dData["to"];
        break;
    }
    $t[$dKey][] = UCFirst($d);
}
ksort($t); // это передвинет 'вых.' в конец массива
$str = '';
foreach($t as $time=>$wDays) {
    $str .= '<strong>' . implode(', ', $wDays) . ': </strong>' . $time . ', ';
}
$str = rtrim($str, ', ');
```

На выходе будет вот так:

> Mon, Tue: 09:00-18:00, Thu: 10:00-19:00, Wen: вых.

От Вашего желаемого результата отличается тем, что если дни имеют одинаковое время, они будут перечислены через запятую, а не дефис.
Это принципиально?

Comment: Потому что дефис подразумевает, что дни идут подряд. А если попадутся, скажем понедельник и четверг с одним временем, а среда с другим, то `Пн,Чт .. Ср ..` будет выглядеть понятнее, чем `Пн-Чт .. Ср ...`

Comment: Все таки вариант с циклом проще в понимании и удобнее, а на счет запятых, решили не заморачиватся и выводить через запятую, спасибо за совет)